# Sightly how to test is a string contain another substring

Tags: sightly

in HTL/Sightly, how can I compare an item is in the array?  or a string contain a sub string?

Like I have array1(apple, banana, orange), array2(apple,pear)

```
<div data-sly-list.item=${array1}>
<div data-sly-test=${array2 == item.name}>if match </div>
 all other code ...
</div>
```

so in the above example, only apple will have the extra div

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.4, you can use `in` relational operator: https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#1143-relational-operators

```
<div data-sly-test="${item in array2}">if match</div>
```